# libGDX label sometimes stops when updating every millisecond

Tags: java, timer, libgdx, label

I'm trying to update a label every millisecond in libGDX for a set amount of time.

However, sometimes the label suddenly stops without an error OR I receive a "String index out of range" error which then crashes my program. These are two separate issues.

Code:

```
Stage stage;
Timer timer = new Timer();
Label countUpLabel;
int countUp;

@Override
public void create () {

    stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));

    //Setting up time label
    BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("04b_19__-32.fnt"));
    LabelStyle labelStyle = new LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE);
    countUpLabel = new Label("Time:\n00000", labelStyle);

    countUpLabel.setPosition(200,200);
    countUpLabel.setAlignment(Align.center);
    countUpLabel.setFontScale(3);

    stage.addActor(countUpLabel);

    //Setting up timer
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (countUp < 3000) {
                countUp++;
                countUpLabel.setText(String.format("Time:\n%d", countUp));
            }else
                timer.cancel();

        }
    }, 0, 1); //every millisecond run the timer
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of libGDX is not thread safe, unless explicitly stated that it is. Also, updating a label every millisecond, while it is only shown about every 16 milliseconds (the refresh rate of your typical display device), isn't a very good approach. So you might want to remove your `timer` and instead update the label when it is actually visible: in the render method:

```
float counter = 0f;
@Override
public void render() {
    if (counter < 3) {
        counter += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        countUpLabel.setText(String.format("Time:\n%01.22f", counter));
    }
    // call glClear, stage.act, stage.draw, etc.
}
```